# Rewrite rule without folders and without file extension

Tags: apache, redirect, http-status-code-301, file-extension

I would like to set a 301 redirect from this :
https://www.mydomain.tld/fr/amp/category/mypage.amphtml
to this :
https://www.mydomain.tld/mypage

For other countries i want to keep language so redirect from this :
https://www.mydomain.tld/en/amp/category/mypage.amphtml
to this :
https://www.mydomain.tld/en/mypage

For now i have these rules for first part :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^fr/amp/category/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*).amphtml$ /$1
RewriteRule ^fr/amp/category/(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But i have the thing don't work as expected.
And i get this result :
https://www.mydomain.tld/mypage.html

Some help or advices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used these simple rules :

```
RewriteRule ^fr/amp/category/(.*).amphtml$ https://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]  
RewriteRule ^en/amp/category/(.*).amphtml$ https://www.mydomain.tld/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```